# How to query overall balance for credit / debit of customer?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sum, pivot, aggregate-functions

Problem: I have a SQL Server table as follows:

| transaction id | timestamp | customer | cost | operation |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 10-12-2020 | 1 | 60 | credit |
| 456 | 11-12-2020 | 2 | 50 | credit |
| 789 | 11-12-2020 | 1 | 20 | debit |
| 000 | 12-12-2020 | 3 | 100 | credit |
| 999 | 15-12-2020 | 2 | 50 | debit |

I want to have an overall real-time balance of the customer as shown below. So that before entering a new record in the above transaction table I will check the balance for that customer and show it to the user.

| customer | balance |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 40 |
| 2 | 0 |
| 3 | 100 |

I tried joins and consolidation but those did not work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just use conditional aggregation:

```
select customer,
    sum(case when operation = 'credit' then cost else -cost end) as balance
from mytable
group by customer
```

The `case` expression in the `sum()` adds or substracts the cost depending if it's a credit or a debit.